# Does recoil affect gunnery, and can RC accessories be used?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, vehicles, drones

When a vehicle or drone attacks from a weapon mount, does recoil modify the attack roll as normal?

If so, can firearm accessories which provide recoil comp. (such as Gyro Stabilization) be built into the vehicle? This is different from the vehicle mod gyro mount from *Arsenal*, which only compensates for the vehicle's movement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking in Arsenal, p105. This hint taken from the [Arsenal Errata](http://www.shadowrun4.com/resources/arsenal_errata_132.pdf).

It looks like this is a known bug, try [this discussion](http://tgdmb.com/viewtopic.php?p=27979) for... a discussion.

Hah! [Drone cheat sheet](http://pavao.org/shadowrun/cheatsheets/SR4DroneCombat.pdf) suggests: 6. Subtract the Recoil Compensation from the number of
rounds fired this Phase, then subtract one; the dif ference is
the recoil modifier.

Comment: I think the drone cheat sheet is mistaken on that count. The recoil penalty for burst and full auto fire modes is not -1 per bullet fired. The page ref. in Arsenal answers my question, though. A motorcycle with 6 body should be able to handle an assault rifle or LMG. Thanks =)

Comment: My pleasure. Is why I tried to find you multiple links.